# get values from two columns in the same row

Tags: php, mysql

I need values from two columns (`cnt`, `link`) in the same row:

```
$st = $db->query("select cnt, link from rolls where def = 1 limit 1");
$str = $st->fetch()['cnt'];
$link = $st->fetch()['link'];
echo $str; // this works
echo $link; // doesn't work - nothing is echoed
```

How to get both values?

Comment: I believe fetch_assoc() will return as assoc array from which you can extract values

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php Check this link

Comment: `$link = $st->fetch()` will attempt to fetch a second row and return nothing, bit the first call will return all of the values from the row, so just fetch it once and use all of the values from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch_assoc() like that:

```
$st = $db->query("select cnt, link from rolls where def = 1 limit 1");
$str = $st->fetch_assoc();
echo $str['cnt'].' '.$str['link '];
```